# Tags for different kinds of NMR: are they necessary?

Tags: discussion

Do we need separate tags for NMR and proton NMR? Do we anticipate enough questions about 13C NMR for the two to merit separate labels?

Comment: And there are far more nuclei than 13C that are used in NMR, 15N is very important, 19F is very useful, 31P as well and even the more exotic nuclei (e.g. Pt) are actually used in NMR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It completely depends on the volume and breadth of NMR questions we will get, so it's hard to say if we will need it. At the moment we have only a single NMR question here, an additional tag will only become useful if we get more than a few dozen questions.

I think that some tag that would separate the simple 1D proton NMR questions from all the more complicated stuff would be useful. But what categories exactly would make sense is hard to say at this moment.

At the moment it's probably best if we use only the [nmr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nmr) tag, but depending on how many questions we get further divisions would be useful.

Comment: I agree. I was not advocating the addition of a new tag; it already existed at the time of posting.

Comment: Agreed, if someone starts asking 2-D COSY/NOESY questions, that would probably warrant a tag.

Comment: I asked a 2d HSQC, HMQC question and had someone tag it with each for me. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/526/121

Answer (score 4):

I would say no.

NMR is mainly on H, and IIRC the only real differences are in the tables--the concept and general rules are the same. Tags are for filtering, and someone who can answer HNMR should be able to do CNMR, if given tables. Not sure, sort of forgotten the nuances of NMR.

Comment: Quadrapole NMR follows very different rules then dipole NMR, as a note.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion would be to have an [nmr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nmr) tag for proton NMR, and then separate tags for [13c-nmr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13c-nmr), etc. for questions that are specific to other types of NMR.  The way I envision it, anything tagged [13c-nmr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13c-nmr) would probably ALSO be tagged [nmr](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nmr).

For example, a question about ppm values for 13C would probably need both tags, but a similar question asking about the differences in ppm values (for proton vs 13C for example) would probably only need the single NMR tag.

It just seems slightly short-sighted to say that all nmr questions would fall under a single tag this early into the beta.  Adding an extra tag to clarify something seems like it would be more helpful than not.